# if user tap the logout button need to show the login screen when he start the app again

Tags: iphone

My iphone app have login screen, and logout button in the app,
requierment was to when user click the logout button,next time he start the application he should get the login screen

solution sould work on 3g/3gs/iphone 4

following are the approaches i found.,
01.calling [[UIApplication sharedApplication] terminateWithSuccess]; and
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] terminate];

02.when user logged to app,write a value to plist and when user click the logout remove the plist value,use this value to propt the user for login screen again or is there anyother approaches available

Regards,
sam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the user's logged in state as a [user default](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/). Check the value in [`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidFinishLaunchingWithOptions%3a) and present the login screen as appropriate. When the user successfully logs in or logs out, update the value appropriately.

Comment: thx this work for me, I checked the above checking in applicationDidBecomeActive: beaause of the iphone multitasking. also i can push the loginview when user click the logout button,hope this also a correct solution.